# How to get List<Model> from firebase in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this Data in Realtime database:

[RealTime Database IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bekye.png)

I want to get the `examQuestion`

When i use this

```
  Future<void> restApiExam() async{
    var url= 'https://taw3ia-ac6b2.firebaseio.com/Exam.json';
    try{
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final List<ExamModel> loadQuiz =[];
      extractedData.forEach((quizId , quizData){
        loadQuiz.add(ExamModel(
          examId : quizId,
          examTitle: quizData['examTitle'],
          examMark: quizData['examMark'],
          examPassingMark: quizData['examPassingMark'],
          examQuestion: (quizData['examQuestion'] as List<dynamic>).map((question) => QuestionModel(
            questionTitle: question['questionTitle'],
            questionAnswer: question['questionAnswer'].cast<String>(),
            questionImage: question['questionImage'],
            questionPoint: question['questionPoint'],
            rightAnswer: question['rightAnswer'],
          )
         ).toList() ,
          isPublic: quizData['isPublic'],
        ));
      });
      _exam = loadQuiz;
      notifyListeners();
    }
    catch(e){
      throw(e);
    }
  }
```

Error :

> E/flutter (27654): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast

My ExamModel :

```
class ExamModel with ChangeNotifier {
  final String examId;
  final String examTitle;
  final String examMark;
  final String examPassingMark;
  final List<QuestionModel> examQuestion;
  final bool isPublic;


  ExamModel({
    @required this.examId,
    @required this.examTitle,
    @required this.examMark,
    @required this.examPassingMark,
    @required this.examQuestion,
    this.isPublic = false,
  });

}
```

My QuestionModel :

```
class QuestionModel with ChangeNotifier{

  final String restById;
  final String questionId;
  final String questionTitle;
  final String questionImage;
  final int questionPoint;
  final List<String> questionAnswer;
  final String rightAnswer;

  QuestionModel({
    @required this.restById,
    @required this.questionId,
    @required this.questionTitle,
    @required this.questionImage,
    @required this.questionPoint,
    @required this.questionAnswer,
    @required this.rightAnswer,
  });

}
```

Comment: You really should leave the image in-line. It makes it easier to analyze.

Comment: Is there a specific line where that error shows up, regarding the List Type? You may have to do some conversion. Data that comes from the Database is dynamic, not typed. You need to convert that data to the types in your model. That might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your image:

[image]

Your field is called "eaxmQuestion" instead of "examQuestion". There is a typo.
I am not sure that will fix your issue, but that is definitely a problem, as in your code you are calling for `quizData['examQuestion']`.

Comment: Ops , thnx bro i really have edit , but i have same issue :(