# Datasnapshot to model

Tags: dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read from Firebase Real-Time Database and save and type cast the data.

Getting this error `FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)` when trying to read the data with:

```
List<RaceModel> racesList = event.snapshot.children
  .map((element) => RaceModel.fromDataSnapshot(element))
  .toList();
```

This is my model(part of it):

```
class RaceModel {
  // General

  ///  Race info ///
  // Race name
  final String name;
  final int id;
  // Race class e.g., human
  final String raceClass;
  // Race subClass e.g., thief
  final String subClass;
  // Race description
  final String description;
  final bool isActive;
  // Basic Unit info ///
  // Basic Unit
  final String basicUnitName;
  final int basicUnitOff;
  final int basicUnitDef;
  final int basicUnitCost;
  RaceModel(
      {required this.name,
      required this.id,
      required this.raceClass,
      required this.subClass,
      required this.description,
      required this.isActive,
      required this.basicUnitName,
      required this.basicUnitOff,
      required this.basicUnitDef,
      required this.basicUnitCost})
factory RaceModel.fromDataSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    return RaceModel(
        name: snapshot.child('name').value.toString(),
        id: int.parse(snapshot.child('id').value.toString()),
        raceClass: snapshot.child('raceClass').value.toString(),
        subClass: snapshot.child('subClass').value.toString(),
        description: snapshot.child('description').value.toString(),
        isActive: snapshot.child('isActive').value.toString() == 'true'
            ? true
            : false,
        basicUnitName: snapshot.child('basicUnitName').value.toString(),
        basicUnitOff:
            int.parse(snapshot.child('basicUnitOff').value.toString()),
        basicUnitDef:
            int.parse(snapshot.child('basicUnitDef').value.toString()),
        basicUnitCost:
            int.parse(snapshot.child('basicUnitCost').value.toString()),)
}
```

json export of the DB:

```
{
  "races": [
    {
      "basicUnitCost": 75,
      "basicUnitDef": 0,
      "basicUnitName": "Thug",
      "basicUnitOff": 0,
      "description": "Ordinary looking, life is cheap and thieves' dens are two-a-penny in a Brittonian tribe. War is when a Britt really shines, quick wits and even quicker fingers enable them to use skills passed down for generations to stash resources for later use. Up to no good? You bet your life they are!",
      "id": 0,
      "isActive": true,
      "name": "Brittonian",
      "raceClass": "Human",
      "racialAbilitiesList": "Homes hold 400 citizens, Hideouts hold 100 citizensitizens && Each building destroyed by thievery yields 6000 crowns && Exploring costs 115% of normal crowns && Ready to go: +25% starting money",
      "subClass": "Thief",
    }
  ],
  "v": 2
}
```

If someone has a better way to do this let me know, thanks.

Comment: Please add your dabase screenshot

Comment: Added a json export of the db

Comment: try to use firebase databse api fetch uri featch

Answer (score 0):

Featch Your Database with the firebase db URI

```
  Future<void> restApiExam() async{
    var url= 'https://taw3ia-ac6b2.firebaseio.com/Exam.json';
    try{
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final List<RaceModel> loadRace =[];
  {
       // Add your remaining code in this try catch  }

    catch(e){
      throw(e);
    }
  }
```

Check out the refrance

[How to get List<Model> from firebase in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66442846/how-to-get-listmodel-from-firebase-in-flutter)